# Thoughts on platform tags?

Tags: discussion

I had previously tagged all the Ford Contour/Mercury Mystique questions with '[CDW27](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_CDW27_platform)', I just did the same thing for some Ford Escape questions ([CD2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_CD2_platform)).

Is this a possible partial solution to the make/model/year conundrum?  All Contours/Mystiques are CDW27.  The '94-'96 Chevy Impalas are [B-bodies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GM_B_platform), while the '00-'13 models are [W-bodies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W-body).

Thoughts?  Vehement opposition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a problem with it, and it will help when people don't realize that some cars are build on the same body, they just have different badgeing

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it can do anything but help. Not all users will know what these tags mean, but they could really help filter out stuff for those who do.